# Display array as raster image in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy

I've got a numpy array in Python and I'd like to display it on-screen as a raster image. What is the simplest way to do this? It doesn't need to be particularly fancy or have a nice interface, all I need to do is to display the contents of the array as a greyscale raster image.

I'm trying to transition some of my IDL code to Python with NumPy and am basically looking for a replacement for the `tv` and `tvscl` commands in IDL.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Depending on your needs, either [matplotlib's `imshow`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) or [glumpy](http://code.google.com/p/glumpy/) are probably the best options.

Matplotlib is infinitely more flexible, but slower (animations in matplotlib can be suprisingly resource intensive even when you do everything right.).   However, you'll have a really wonderful, full-featured plotting library at your disposal.

Glumpy is perfectly suited for the quick, openGL based display and animation of a 2D numpy array, but is much more limited in what it does.  If you need to animate a series of images or display data in realtime, it's a far better option than matplotlib, though.

Using matplotlib (using the pyplot API instead of pylab):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data...
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,200), np.linspace(-2,2,200))
x, y = x - x.mean(), y - y.mean()
z = x * np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)

# Plot the grid
plt.imshow(z)
plt.gray()
plt.show()
```

Using glumpy:

```
import glumpy
import numpy as np

# Generate some data...
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,200), np.linspace(-2,2,200))
x, y = x - x.mean(), y - y.mean()
z = x * np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)

window = glumpy.Window(512, 512)
im = glumpy.Image(z.astype(np.float32), cmap=glumpy.colormap.Grey)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    im.blit(0, 0, window.width, window.height)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks again @Joe, [this answer made me solve my own question!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003094/how-can-i-speed-up-an-animation/5471487#5471487)

Answer (score 7):

Using ipython in the pylab interactive mode, you could do:

```
$ ipython pylab
In [1]: imshow(your_array)
```

or not in pylab mode:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: from pylab import *
In [2]: imshow(your_array)
In [3]: pylab.show()
```

or without the pylab namespace thing:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
In [2]: pyplot.imshow(your_array)
In [3]: pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick addition: for displaying with matplotlib, if you want the image to appear "raster", i.e., pixelized without smoothing, then you should include the option interpolation='nearest' in the call to imshow.